# Oracle APEX - issues processing Excel data

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a File Browse on my page that allows the user to select an Excel file. Then, when button is clicked, page is submitted and I call a process that retrieves the data from the `apex_application_temp_files` based on the filename selected.

The data I display in the classic report using the following query

```
SELECT col001,col002
FROM apex_application_temp_files f, 
     table( apex_data_parser.parse(
              p_content                     => f.blob_content,
              p_add_headers_row             => 'N',
              p_xlsx_sheet_name             => NULL,
              p_max_rows                    => 500,
              p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
              p_file_name                   => f.filename
           ))
WHERE f.name = :P2_FILE_BROWSE
```

Data displays just fine but when I try to process the data instaed of displaying it, no data gets retrieved. I use the same query:

```
FOR x IN (SELECT col001,col002
    FROM apex_application_temp_files f, 
    table( apex_data_parser.parse(
              p_content                     => f.blob_content,
              p_add_headers_row             => 'N',
              p_xlsx_sheet_name             => NULL,
              p_max_rows                    => 500,
              p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
              p_file_name                   => f.filename
          ))
WHERE f.name = :P2_FILE_BROWSE) 
LOOP
    apex_debug.message('First field is ', x.col001);
    apex_debug.message('Second field is ', x.col002);
END LOOP;
```

Not sure what is going on and why data does not get displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like records are getting retrieved but the debug is not displaying them because %s is missing in the message. Also, the debug needs to be enabled before issuing the debug statements.

```
apex_debug.enable;
apex_debug.message('First field is %s', x.col001);
apex_debug.message('Second field is %s', x.col002);
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. I guess I was used to console.log where `%s` was not necessary